# How to handle Throw exception + close connection

Tags: java

I have a function that works with a database. If something wrong happens I want to throw an exception, and I also want that all resources have to be closed.

Is this a good way to do it? There is a better way to do it?

```
public Strint getStuff(Integer id) throws Exception {

    String result = "";

    Connection connection = db.openConection();
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
       // DO STUFF WITH DB
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        rs.close();
        db.closeConection(connection);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. You can skip `catch` part of try-catch-finally block
2. You should check that `rs` is not null

Comment: Also, since `rs.close()` and `db.closeConnection(connection)` can throw exceptions, each should be wrapped in a try/catch block. Otherwise, any exception they throw will suppress an exception from `DO STUFF WITH DB` (which is probably more important). (However, in Java 7, a suppressed exception can still be recovered, so this is less of an issue. You still don't want an exception from `rs.close()` to prevent closing the db connection.)

Answer (score 8):

If you can, use [Java 7's new try...catch](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/java-7-try-with-resources-explained.html).

```
try(NewResource res = new NewResource("Res1 closing")){
  res.doSomeWork("Listening to podcast");
} catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println("Exception: "+
  e.getMessage()+" Thrown by: "+e.getClass().getSimpleName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may verify the connection status in the finally or after that...

Something like this:

```
public Strint getStuff(Integer id) throws Exception {

    String result = "";

    Connection connection = db.openConection();
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
       // DO STUFF WITH DB
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }

    try{
        // Verify ResultSet status and close if open
        if(rs != null){
             rs.close();
        }
        // Verify the connection status and close if oppened
        if(((connection != null)) && (connection.isConnected())){
             connection.close();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){

    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: The last try..catch should be inside of finally block of the first try..catch, or the connection and the ResultSet will remain open after the exception!

Answer (score 1):

Usually I end up writing methods like

```
public static void tryClose(ResultSet rs) {
    if (rs == null) { return; }
    try { rs.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { // log the exception just in case }
}
```

and put them in some utility or common base class, using them like this

```
Connection c = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    // your db code here
} finally {
    Base.tryClose(rs); // or possibly just tryClose(rs);
    Base.tryClose(c);  // or possibly just tryClose(c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I often use the following idiom:

```
public Strint getStuff(Integer id) throws Exception {

    Connection connection = db.openConection();
    try {
        ResultSet rs = connection.execute....();

        try {
           String result = "";
           // ... DO STUFF WITH DB ...
           return result;
        } finally {
           rs.close();
        }
    } finally {
        db.closeConection(connection);
    }
}
```

This works with all JDK's out there and reliably disposes of resources in event of an exception of any kind.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of catching generic `"Exception"`, its always better to catch specific exception and as @Andrew pointed its better to check for `resultset` not null.

Comment: In this case, I think it doesn't make sense to catch specific exceptions.

Comment: While generally true, this advice doesn't apply here. In this case he simply shouldn't be catching the exception.

Comment: why do you both think its not good to catch Specific exception ?Explain.

Comment: @SajanChandran - There's no reason to catch a more specific exception because there's no reason to catch any exception at all.